# selecting the dropdown from an page loaded through a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading a page through a div because of iframe restrictions. What I want to do is access the page contents and select the first item in the dropdown. If the id of the dropdown is called myDropdown or something like "ctl00_ctl65_g_549adf60_cb6b_4794_af15_99ce724b040f_FormControl0_V1_I1_D2", how do i access this to select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").load("https://page.aspx");
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="topBar">
  <a href="#" id="load_home"> Rate!</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get a cross origin error in console?  And what webpage specifically?

Comment: Hello. Please, kindly note that you are loading the version 1.11.1 of jQuery before <html> opening tag and then you are loading an older version of jQuery again.

Comment: That was due to the snippet editor

Comment: Do you have some JS code trying to access the select, but failing to? If so, please post it.

Comment: its a sharepoint.aspx page. no error. It loads. I am just trying to preselect a dropdown option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script.

```
    var interval;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#load_home").on("click", function () {
            $('.calc-loader').show();
            $("#content").load("HtmlPage5.html");

            interval = setInterval(function () {
                console.log($('#content select option').length);
                if ($('#content select option').length > 2) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $('.calc-loader').hide();
                    $('#content select option:eq(3)').prop("selected",true);
                    $('#content select').trigger('change');
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why set the value to the value? Just set the selected to true as in my answer.

Comment: I know. That's what I suggested

Comment: I had updated latest code, used interval because on .aspx page options of dropdown populated after some time. also trigger change event because there is some code executes after change of selection

Comment: He has shared dropdown code on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v0nni/wumk46bs/. Initially my code was not working for him so i have modified as above and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it in the .load callback or delegate:

```
$(function() {
  $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").load("https://page.aspx",function() {
      $("#myDropdown option:eq(2)").prop{"selected",true);
      // if you have event handlers on the select, you want to trigger them
      $("#myDropdown").change(); 
    });
  });
});
```

Delegation:

```
$("#content").on("change","#myDropdown",function() {
  // delegated the change event to the container
});
```

Comment: Does it need to be accessed in this way, or does it become part of the DOM on load, able to be accessed normally?

Comment: This is an uncomplete answer. OP doesn't have a specified `id` of the select box aswell as the value of the first option.

Comment: @Kinduser With the information given in the question, the examples I gave are covering most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modular `findAndSelect()` function using pure JS.  Parameters are the string ID of the select, and the string value of the option you want to select.

Say your html is : `<select id="sel"><option>option1</option></select>` and you want to set #sel to 'option1', you call `findAndSelect('sel','option1');`

```
function findAndSelect (elementId, optionToSelect) {

  function findRelevantIndex(elementId) {
    var optionsArr = document.getElementById(elementId).options;
    var optionsLen = optionsArr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < optionsLen; i++) {
      if (optionsArr[i].text == optionToSelect) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    console.log('found no matching option as ' + optionToSelect);
    return 0;
  }
  document.getElementById(elementId).selectedIndex = findRelevantIndex(elementId);
  console.log('new selected index for ' + elementId + ' is ' + document.getElementById(elementId).selectedIndex);
}
```